# Building Real Time Applications On VPS

Tags: php, node.js, web-applications, vps

I want to build a real time application "Chat Application for instance"
I already tried this tutorial http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

And it works fine on my windows 7 
But the issue now is i want to use it on vps.
I have root access to vps 
but i don't know how to make the application always be running.

Note : I have putty for SSH Connection

Second questions is : what is the best for building that kind of applications.
I use PHP as my master programming language , so is it enough to build those applications or i should use something like NodeJS instead "zero knowledge at the moment"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using something like Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/). Basically you set it up to run the server script and then it constantly monitors to make sure it is running. If for some reason the script stops running it automatically starts it back up. I know it isn't exactly what you want but on Ratchet's site they do a good job of explaining how to setup supervisor for a PHP based websocket server (http://socketo.me/docs/deploy#supervisor).

I have created quite a few PHP based websocket server applications and never had a problem with them. So no need to move to Node unless you want to or you start to run into limitations you can't overcome with PHP.